# How to group data in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, process, operating-system, scheduler

I was trying make a non pre-emptive longest job first job scheduler. I know  the algorithm for the sjf.

At first I sorted the arrays according to the arrival time

```
for(int i=0;i<noOfProcesses;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<noOfProcesses;j++)
    {
        if(arrivalTime[i]<arrivalTime[j])
        {
            temp=processID[j];
            processID[j]=processID[i];
            processID[i]=temp;

            temp=arrivalTime[j];
            arrivalTime[j]=arrivalTime[i];
            arrivalTime[i]=temp;

            temp=burstTime[j];
            burstTime[j]=burstTime[i];
            burstTime[i]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I was trying to make the scheduler. I tried for the shortest job first but I cant make it work for longest job first.
The processes who have arrival time less than the burst time of the current process is to be put into the queue in descending order of the burst time.

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    btime=btime+burstTime[j];
    int min=burstTime[k];
    for(i=k;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (btime>=arrivalTime[i] && burstTime[i]<min)
        {
            temp=processID[k];
            processID[k]=processID[i];
            processID[i]=temp;

            temp=arrivalTime[k];
            arrivalTime[k]=arrivalTime[i];
            arrivalTime[i]=temp;

            temp=burstTime[k];
            burstTime[k]=burstTime[i];
            burstTime[i]=temp;
        }
    }
    k++;
}
```

This code was working for selecting processes in ascending order of burst time but I cant make it work for the descennding order

Example :

Process ID    Arrival Time      Burst Time

1               11                22
2               12                24
3               14                28
4               22                44

this may be taken as a sample input

Process ID    Arrival Time      Burst Time

1               11                22
2               14                28
3               12                24
4               22                44

this will be the the output as the process 1 will run from time 11 to 22 
meanwhile, process 2 and 3 will have arrived the process 1 will finish on 11+22=33 so the cpu will have 2 choices to run ie process 2 and 3 but even though process 2 arrived before 3, cpu will select process process 3 next because it has a high burst time the code written selects process 2 because it has low burst time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: can you have a look for the time-being

Comment: If you want anyone to help you then you will at least need to provide a [mcve]. You will learn more by debugging this yourself though.

Comment: Are `processID` `arrivalTime` and `burstTime` all supposed to be linked to each other? (such as `processID[0]` being associated with `arrivalTime[0]`).  If such is the case, is there a reason not to pack these data together in a struct and then just have an array of the struct?  To then sort the structure, is there anything to prevent you from using `qsort`?

Comment: yes @ChristianGibbons I've updated the question

Comment: There is a couple of bits of code now in the question.  However, it does not compile, much less cleanly compile.

Comment: the variable `k` is never initialized in the posted code, however; it is being used as a index into some array.  Similar considerations exist for the variable: `noOfProcesses` .    What do you mean by: `burstTime`?  is this the expected time the process will execute -or- the time the process has already executed -or- ???

Comment: the posted code looks like it is working with 3 separate arrays `arrivalTime[]` `processID[]` `burstTime[]`  Since those three arrays are tightly related, why are they in separate arrays?

Comment: these are the time which a process arrives to the cpu, how much time it takes to complete and what is the process ID of each process

Comment: I solved it by taking a struct @ChristianGibbons thanks all for help